# How to change the format of thumbnails into wordpress theme?

Tags: post-thumbnails, thumbnails

dear community.
I have question about changing the format of thumbnail into WordPress theme.

I want to change all generated images format into a theme to *.webp. I already have generated *.webp images. Where I can do it into WordPress? Where I can change the format of generated thumbnails?

Best Regards
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Right now, WordPress [does not support](https://codex.wordpress.org/Uploading_Files) *.webp files. You will get an error when trying to upload a file with that extension. There are various plugins, including Jetpack, that will automatically convert uploaded jp/gif/png images to webp if they are requested by browsers that supports webp (which at the moment excludes Safari).